# C#: WPF - multipage-application pass data between pages

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, object, state

I have multi-page application (WPF), i have used it for genetic algorithms my app looks like this
[image]

this multi-page application is done with identically logic as contains link below.
http://azerdark.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/multi-page-application-in-wpf/

My question is how can i pass information between pages with object state. I mean that i run genetic algorithm and between GA is running i'll click on graph button it opens new page Graph (in same window) and show some statistics then i go back to main page and everything run in same time. But in this moment it always only make new Page and all data is deleted so i need something to pass data between pages.

The solution should be in this part of code:

```
public interface ISwitchable
{
  void UtilizeState( object state );
}

public static class Switcher
{
    public static PageSwitcher pageSwitcher;

    public static void Switch(UserControl newPage, object state)
    {
        pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage, state);
    }
}
    public void Navigate(UserControl nextPage, object state)
    {
        this.Content = nextPage;
        ISwitchable s = nextPage as ISwitchable;

        if (s != null)
            s.UtilizeState(state);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("NextPage is not ISwitchable! "
              + nextPage.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

//Part of code in MainMenu

```
private void OriginCovering_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
   Switcher.Switch(new OriginCovering());
}
```

//Part of code in OriginCovering

```
public void UtilizeState(object state){
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: MVVM ? Many Views, 1 ViewModel ;)

Comment: ?? i dont understand what u mean